# hasOverlappingRendering() and two ImageViews

Tags: android, performance, rendering

I have a custom `View`, which contains, amongst others, two `ImageViews` on top of each other.
I set `hasOverlappingRendering()` to return false, and haven't had any issues while setting alpha.

But doesn't it really contain overlapping rendering (the two `ImageViews`)? Shouldn't this be a (graphical) error of some sort?

Comment: I think the problem is described from 1:32 to 2:02 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIy8g8yNhNk&feature=youtu.be&t=1m32s). It's not necessarily a obvious problem

Comment: As well some more details here --> https://youtu.be/vQZFaec9NpA?t=29m51s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A late answer.. But better late than never. The answer is that doesn't contain overlapping rendering. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIy8g8yNhNk&feature=youtu.be&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&t=247) really useful.

Google engineers are explaining with an example what is happening when you return false from the hasOverlappingRendering().